# How can I make query in PHP to search start_date and end_date

Tags: php, oracle

I can't convert this query from Oracle database to PHP.

```
<input type="date" name="stardate" value="startdate" id="startdate" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["startdate"]);?>"> 
<input type="date" name="enddate" value="enddate" id="enddate" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["enddate"]);?>">
```

This is my query that is correct, but I don't know how to place it in PHP:

```
SELECT *
  FROM datepick
 WHERE start_date not between to_date('03/28/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('03/30/2019','mm/dd/yyyy')
 and end_date not between to_date('03/28/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('03/30/2019','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

After form submission get date in variables and stablish php-mysql connection using mysqli or pdo than with concatenation you can pass those value to mysql query.

```
<?php
// support you done form submit with get/post

$stardate = $_REQUEST['stardate']; // 03/28/2019
$enddate = $_REQUEST['enddate']; // 03/30/2019

// mysqli connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM datepick WHERE 
start_date not between to_date('".$stardate."','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('".$enddate."','mm/dd/yyyy')
and end_date not between to_date('".$stardate."','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('".$enddate."','mm/dd/yyyy')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r ($row);
// check output and modify code accordingly
?>
```